# How to call a Toast in the Class?

Tags: android, android-toast, public-method

The structure of my project is following:
Activity - Fragment - Class

The issue: in Class according to some conditions show a Toast

The problem: I can't call a Context from the class by getActivity()

How to resolve it in the best way? Create some Public class or variable?

Comment: Your question is extremely vague, I recommend looking into how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I need to call the Toast from Class (TextWatcher) - it's not a vague qestion

Comment: Did you read the link? I think you should read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well. You do not provide any information on how you have attempted to solve your problem, nor have you provided any code to for us to reproduce the issue. It *is* a vague question, and providing more information will help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just send the `Context` to your class constructor.
Like this:

```
private Context context;

public MyClass(Context ctx) {
context = ctx;
}
```

And then use it to show a toast.

Comment: Passing a `Context` around without knowing the use-case is a good way to [cause memory leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) in your application.

Comment: @Bryan One can use `WeakReference` then.

Comment: That is one way of doing it, but not necessary for *every* use case. Which I was I was hesitant to post an answer based on such little information.

Answer (score 1):

Without much context, the only way I can recommend triggering a `Toast` message from a class other than an `Activity` is to use a `Listener` interface:

```
public class Unknown {

    public interface UnknownListener {

        void displayMessage(CharSequence message);

    }

    private UnknownListener mUnknownListener;

    private final String mToastMessage = "Unknown message";

    public Unknown() {}

    public void setUnknownListener(UnknownListener listener) {
        mUnknownListener = listener;
    }

    private void doSomething() {
        if(mUnknownListener != null) {
            mUnknownListener.displayMessage(mToastMessage);
        }
    }

}
```

Then implement the interface in your `Activity`, making sure to remove the reference in a corresponding lifecycle method:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Unknown.UnknownListener {

    private Unknown mUnknown;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mUnknown = new Unknown();
        mUnknown.setUnknownListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mUnknown.setUnknownListener(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void displayMessage(CharSequence message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your replying. Maybe it's the most proper solution, but I prefer to go by the simplest way with calling the constructor. However, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can call Toast in Activity class as follows -

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```

To show in Fragment or another class, you have to pass the reference of the Activity or Context in the Constructor of Fragment or that particular class.Eg,

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment(activity);
```

In Fragment Class -

```
Class MyFragment extends Fragment{
     private Activity mActivity;

     MyFragment(Activity activity){
         mActivity = activity;
     }

     void showToast(){
         Toast.makeText(mActivity, text, duration);
     }

}
```